# How to calculate the 2D transformation matrix between two triangles in javascript

Tags: javascript, matrix, geometry, paperjs, coordinate-transformation

I want to calculate the 2D transformation matrix that allows transforming a triangle into another.
Both triangles points coordinates are known.
I usually use Paper.js to deal with matrices but this use case is not covered by it.
I still used it to illustrate my problem in this [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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).
Note that in this example, I selected points coordinates and matrix transformations to illustrate how complex the transformation can be but the idea is to be able to solve it for all possible cases.
[image]

I think that I found the theoretical answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557507/how-to-find-a-transformation-matrix-given-coordinates-of-two-triangles-in-r2) but I have hard time programming it in javascript because my knowledge of matrices math is limited.
Does someone know a javascript library that can solve this kind of problem ?
Or does someone know how to solve it in javascript ?

Here is the code that I used to illustrate the problem:

```js
// These are the known input points
const p1A = new Point(0, 0);
const p2A = new Point(25, 0);
const p3A = new Point(0, 15);

// This is the matrix that I want to calculate
const matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.translate(40, 0);
matrix.rotate(30);
matrix.scale(1.2, -0.2);
matrix.rotate(-70);

// These are the known transformed points
const p1B = p1A.transform(matrix);
const p2B = p2A.transform(matrix);
const p3B = p3A.transform(matrix);

// Draw the elements to better visualize the problem
drawPoint(p1A, 'p1A', 'red');
drawPoint(p2A, 'p2A', 'cyan');
drawPoint(p3A, 'p3A', 'lime');
drawPoint(p1B, 'p1B', 'red');
drawPoint(p2B, 'p2B', 'cyan');
drawPoint(p3B, 'p3B', 'lime');

drawPolygon([p1A, p2A, p3A], 'A');
drawPolygon([p1B, p2B, p3B], 'B');

// Scale things up to better see.
project.activeLayer.fitBounds(view.bounds.scale(0.8));


//
// METHODS
//

function drawPoint(point, name, color) {
    new Path.Circle({
        center: point,
        radius: 1,
        fillColor: color
    });
    new PointText({
        content: name,
        point: point - [0, 1.5],
        justification: 'center',
        fontSize: 1
    });
}

function drawPolygon(points, name) {
    const path = new Path({
        segments: points,
        strokeColor: 'grey',
        closed: true
    });
    new PointText({
        content: name,
        point: path.bounds.center,
        justification: 'center',
        fontSize: 2
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I followed this [article](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Ebaker/149.1.02w/handouts/i_affine_II.pdf) that proposed a solution to this problem in a simple manner and implemented it myself.
The solution consists in calculating, for each triangle, the matrix that can do the transformation between the "standard triangle" (a triangle with coordinates (1,0),(0,1),(0,0)) and the given triangle.
We use these matrices to transform the first triangle to the standard triangle (by inverting the calculated matrix) then to the target triangle

Here is the completed [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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), including the solution.
Here is the matrix computation relevant part:

```js
function calculateResetMatrix(p1, p2, p3) {
    return new Matrix(
        p1.x - p3.x, p1.y - p3.y,
        p2.x - p3.x, p2.y - p3.y,
        p3.x, p3.y
    );
}

function calculateMatrix(p1, p2, p3, p1Transformed, p2Transformed, p3Transformed) {
    return calculateResetMatrix(p1, p2, p3).inverted()
        .prepend(calculateResetMatrix(p1Transformed, p2Transformed, p3Transformed));
}
```

And here is the full code:

```js
// These are the known input points
const p1A = new Point(0, 0);
const p2A = new Point(25, 0);
const p3A = new Point(0, 15);

// This is the matrix that I want to calculate
const matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.translate(40, 0);
matrix.rotate(30);
matrix.scale(1.2, -0.2);
matrix.rotate(-70);

// These are the known transformed points
const p1B = p1A.transform(matrix);
const p2B = p2A.transform(matrix);
const p3B = p3A.transform(matrix);

// And here is the calculated matrix
const calculatedMatrix = calculateMatrix(
    p1A, p2A, p3A,
    p1B, p2B, p3B
);
// From which we calculate the transformed points
const p1C = p1A.transform(matrix);
const p2C = p2A.transform(matrix);
const p3C = p3A.transform(matrix);

// Draw the elements to better visualize the problem
drawPoint(p1A, 'p1A', 'red');
drawPoint(p2A, 'p2A', 'cyan');
drawPoint(p3A, 'p3A', 'lime');
drawPoint(p1B, 'p1B', 'red');
drawPoint(p2B, 'p2B', 'cyan');
drawPoint(p3B, 'p3B', 'lime');
drawPoint(p1C, 'p1   & C', 'red');
drawPoint(p2C, 'p2   & C', 'cyan');
drawPoint(p3C, 'p3   & C', 'lime');

drawPolygon([p1A, p2A, p3A], 'A');
drawPolygon([p1B, p2B, p3B], 'B');

// Scale things up to better see.
project.activeLayer.fitBounds(view.bounds.scale(0.8));


//
// METHODS
//

function drawPoint(point, name, color) {
    new Path.Circle({
        center: point,
        radius: 1,
        fillColor: color,
        opacity: 0.5
    });
    new PointText({
        content: name,
        point: point - [0, 1.5],
        justification: 'left',
        fontSize: 1
    });
}

function drawPolygon(points, name) {
    const path = new Path({
        segments: points,
        strokeColor: 'grey',
        closed: true
    });
    new PointText({
        content: name,
        point: path.bounds.center,
        justification: 'center',
        fontSize: 2
    });
}

function calculateResetMatrix(p1, p2, p3) {
    return new Matrix(
        p1.x - p3.x, p1.y - p3.y,
        p2.x - p3.x, p2.y - p3.y,
        p3.x, p3.y
    );
}

function calculateMatrix(p1, p2, p3, p1Transformed, p2Transformed, p3Transformed) {
    return calculateResetMatrix(p1, p2, p3).inverted()
        .prepend(calculateResetMatrix(p1Transformed, p2Transformed, p3Transformed));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The math behind this problem is described in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation). Have a look at the section on *augmented matrix* which es needed for a transformation that includes the translation.

In JavaScript, all required operations can be done using the library [linalg.js](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ejdr/linalg_js/doc/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I ended up following another path though.